# Command line options for java

Tags: java

I have been developing java programs using eclipse but for some time I wanted to edit/run (mostly for learning purposes) it on a command line on windows e.g. cmd - the only thing is in cmd (unlike ubuntu or shells editors), it doesnt do any formattting / color coding for any of the types or keywords - it looks like i am writing on a notepad.  Is there any way I could get a colorful formatted editor for cmd for writing and compiling java programs.  I still dont want to use intellisense or other IDE features - just something more than black and white cmd will do.

Thanks

Comment: why not [vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php)

Comment: You're probably looking for Notepad++

Comment: Notepad++ has a console version?

Comment: @PaulHicks and thus began the war of text editors

Comment: hell, you can even still use eclipse, and still just compile from the command line

Comment: Install cygwin and use vim?

Comment: Heh :)  Hopefully there won't be a war over this.  I just didn't know that you could run Notepad++ in a console.

Comment: @Ralf vim runs fine in cmd window, don't need cygwin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an editor that will run directly on the command line, you can try Emacs or Vim.  If you just want a simple editor with syntax highlighting, GEdit or Notepad++ will work well.

Comment: how would i compile on notepad++?

Comment: @Tintin don't you want to compile from the command line?

Comment: @Tintin Although using the command line is probably just as easy, theres an answer on how to [compile and run java from notepad++ here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204147/java-compile-and-run-using-notepad-and-nppexec)

Comment: yeah but I wanted to do it all in one place... I am starting to look at Emacs now.  thanks.

Comment: If you want to compile from an editor, you are getting into the realm of IDEs. When I use vim, I don't use vim to compile anything, I compile from the command line, using some compiler or build tool (I am using maven to build on my current project)

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've actually used a program called PSPad which I thought was good.  I've also used Notepad++.  There are ways to run the command line from both editors.