# Could not find or load main class Java Error Notepad++

Tags: java, notepad++

I've implemented "Java Compile" and "Compile and Run" (the second as Java Compile and Run) as described in this answer: [Java compile and run using notepad++ and nppexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204147/java-compile-and-run-using-notepad-and-nppexec).

Note: I'm using 1.8.0_20 rather than 1.7.0 as described in the answer.

However, when I try to run HelloWorld (as found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm) to test the compiler, I get the following response, including a "Could not find or load main class" error:

```
NPP_EXEC: "Java Compile and Run"
CD: C:\Users\Bova\Documents
Current directory: C:\Users\Bova\Documents
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java" -classpath "C:\Users\Bova\Documents"    "HelloWorld"
Process started >>>
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

What do I need to change to avoid this error?

Comment: If you use 1.7.0 you will have to add JavaFX to the classpath manually.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in Notepad++ too. What I did to fix it was I went to the Plugins menu, clicked on NppExec, and selected `Follow $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)`. After that I can run programs just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The very first line of `HelloWorld.java` reads:

```
package helloworld;
```

Java packages are mapped to directories on the filesystem, so the interpreter expects to find `HelloWorld.class` inside a `helloworld` directory. Move the `.class` file to a `helloworld` subdir and run it as:

```
> java helloworld.HelloWorld
```

**from the parent directory** (i.e. the directory which contains `helloworld/`).

Comment: Maybe, I'm doing it wrong, but I've created the "helloworld" subdir and moved the .class file into it, but I get the same error.

Comment: Probably that's a problem with how Notepad++ executes the `.class` file. Try removing the `package helloworld` line and see if it works.

Comment: Just tried this, seems to compile normally, but compile and run command starts then doesn't do anything (starts but doesn't finish or throw error).

Also tried with another version of Hello World (found here:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html). Got the same error.

For reference, the file is saved as HelloWorld.java